# Does packagename:::function cannot be used or modify?

Tags: r

I am working on a project and I need to modify some funciton of existing package. Some of these functions are not exported and I only can acess them via `packagename:::function` in R. Are these function cannot be modified or must be not used or we do not allowded to modify them since there are not exported by the author? any help please?

Note that: I need to build my own function based on some existing function from the package. The existing functions are very helful and for my project I need to modify them to what I need. Then I will use these functions in my project only for my use. I will not modify the package itself. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean exactly by "modify"? Change the source code and rebuild the package? Change the function temporarily from within R (possibly using trace or assignInNamespace)?

Comment: @Roland I need to build a function for my project. However, there are some functions are already exist from `VineCopula` package. I need to change these funcitons (not so much) to what I exactely need for my project. Then, these function will be only for my use and not modifying the package directely. That is, I take these function from the package and change what I need to change and use them for my project only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the source code, paste it in your R script (and give it another name), modify the code as you want and run the function. Then it will be saved in your environment and you can run it as a normal function. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much. Is that allowded as a researsher or I cannot since these functions are not exproted.

Comment: As long as your modifications have are scientifically sound, I think you are alright. Just make sure that you report what you changed in your paper/report for reproducibility! If you think this is your answer, please accept/mark it as one :).